# Tensor product, Tensor components, multiple definitions.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I have search the forum for answer to my question without much success.
I am struggling putting together two definitions of the tensor product and tensors in general. I am restricting my question to only one vector space V.

Definition 1: Is the standard definition that a tensor is a multilinear map $f:V^*\times...\times V^*\times V\times...\times V \longrightarrow \mathbb{k}$. The tensor product is defined to be :
$(f\otimes g)(...) = f(...)g(...)$

Definition 2: The tensor product is a new vector space where we want to define some product between vectors. We want to define the tensor product as a list of properties the product should have :
\begin{align}
\lambda(v\otimes w) = (\lambda v)\otimes w = v \otimes(\lambda w)\\
(v_1 + v_2)\otimes w = v_1\otimes w + v_2\otimes w\\
v\otimes(w_1 + w_2) = v\otimes w_1 + v\otimes w_2
\end{align}
Then a tensor is a linear combination $\forall v \in V, w \in W$:
\begin{align}
\sum v_i\otimes w_i
\end{align}

I know how to prove that the space $V\longrightarrow V$ is isomorphic to $V\otimes V^*$.

Here are my questions :

1) I don't know exactly to what property $(f\otimes g)(...) = f(...)g(...)$ refer to exactly in the second definition of tensor. For example if we have $f$ to be a (0,2) tensor and $g$ a (0,2) tensor. the product would be a (0,4) tensor so $(f\otimes g)(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4) = f(v_1,v_2)g(v_3,v_4)$. To what kind of tensor in definition 2 would this be isomorphic ?

2) I am confused about what is a tensor component. As I understand tensor components are the scalars that form a linear combination of basis tensors. In definition 1, I see books defining the tensor components as $T^{a_1,...,a_k}_{b_1,...,b_k} = T(a_1,...,a_k,b_1,...,b_k)$. Where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are a basis of the vector space and covector space. For definition 2 I see tensor component written as :
\begin{align}
\sum\sum A_{ij}a_i\otimes b_j
\end{align}

How do these components relate ?

3) I was trying to work out a basic example of an endomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by using the two definitions but couldn't end up with the same set of components...

Thanks for any help !

Comment: I'm writing a long answer for you. Please don't delete the question for whatever reason :P

Comment: Aha I so appreciate your time !

Comment: Note that $V^V$ is only isomorphic to $V \otimes V^*$ when $V$ is finite dimensional....

Comment: Yes sorry I skip that point.

Comment: @user149705 I think I'm done

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's assume everything has finite dimension here.

> 1) I don't know exactly to what property $(f\otimes g)(...) = f(...)g(...)$ refer to exactly in the second definition of tensor. For example if we have $f$ to be a (0,2) tensor and $g$ a (0,2) tensor. the product would be a (0,4) tensor so $(f\otimes g)(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4) = f(v_1,v_2)g(v_3,v_4)$. To what kind of tensor in definition 2 would this be isomorphic ?

A tensor product of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is a pair $(\mathsf{T} ,t)$, where $\mathsf{T} $ is a vector space and $t\colon V \times W \to \mathsf{T} $ is bilinear, such that if $\{{\bf v}_i\}$ and $\{{\bf w}_j\}$ are bases for $V$ and $W$, then $\{t({\bf v}_i,{\bf w}_j)\}$ spans $\mathsf{T} $, and if given $b\colon V \times W \to Z$ is any bilinear map (arriving at an arbitrary vector space $Z$), there is an unique linear map $\overline{b}\colon \mathsf{T}  \to Z$ such that $\overline{b}\circ t = b$. Meaning that bilinear maps $b$ factor through $\mathsf{T} $ and we have all the information needed in a single linear map $\overline{b}$. One then proves that all tensor products of $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic, and so we put the usual notations $\mathsf{T} \equiv V \otimes W$, $t \equiv \otimes$, and write ${\bf v} \otimes {\bf w}$ for $t({\bf v},{\bf w})$.

An explicit construction is to take the free vector space with basis $V \times W$, and take its quotient by the subspace spanned by the elements of the form \begin{align} &({\bf v}_1+{\bf v}_2,{\bf w}) - ({\bf v}_1,{\bf w})-({\bf v}_2,{\bf w}), \\ & ({\bf v},{\bf w}_1+{\bf w}_2)-({\bf v},{\bf w}_1)-({\bf v},{\bf w}_2), \\ & (\lambda{\bf v},{\bf w}) - ({\bf v},\lambda{\bf w}).\end{align}
We then denote the class of $({\bf v},{\bf w})$ by ${\bf v} \otimes {\bf w}$.

One generalizes all of this by considering more spaces, writing "multilinear maps" instead of "bilinear maps", and so on. The space $${\frak T}^{(r,s)}(V) = \{  f\colon (V^\ast)^r \times V^s \to \Bbb R \mid f \text{ is multilinear}  \}$$is isomorphic to $V^{\otimes r}\otimes (V^\ast)^{\otimes s}$, and that isomorphism does not depend on a choice of basis (so it is better than your average run-of-the-mill isomorphism). Well, being more honest, we use a basis to define the isomorphism, but then we check that it would be same if we started with another basis. We say that $T \in {\frak T}^{(r,s)}(V)$ is a $r-$times contravariant and $s-$times covariant tensor. We of course have an operation $$\otimes \colon {\frak T}^{(r,s)}(V) \times {\frak T}^{(r',s')}(V) \to {\frak T}^{(r+r',s+s')}(V).$$

Now we hopefully understand a little better what a tensor product is, we can simply note that ${\frak T}^{(0,4)}(V) \cong (V^\ast)^{\otimes 4}$, and if $\{{\bf v}_i\}$ is a basis for $V$, and $\{{\bf v}^i\}$ is the dual basis, then $$f \otimes g = \sum_{i,j,k,\ell} f_{ijk\ell} {\bf v}^i \otimes {\bf v}^j\otimes {\bf v}^k \otimes {\bf v}^\ell,$$where $f_{ijkl} = f({\bf v}_i,{\bf v}_j,{\bf v}_k,{\bf v}_\ell)$ and ${\bf v}^i \otimes {\bf v}^j\otimes {\bf v}^k \otimes {\bf v}^\ell \in {\frak T}^{(0,4)}(V)$. It corresponds to that same expression seen as a linear combination of ${\bf v}^i \otimes {\bf v}^j \otimes {\bf v}^k \otimes {\bf v}^\ell$, *the class of $({\bf v}^i,{\bf v}^j,{\bf v}^k,{\bf v}^\ell)$ in that quotient* - that expression is an element of $(V^\ast)^{\otimes 4}$. Maybe I shouldn't have been lazy and used another notation for the classes until now - I'll gladly explain it all again if you have trouble following.

> 2) I am confused about what is a tensor component. As I understand tensor components are the scalars that form a linear combination of basis tensors. In definition 1, I see books defining the tensor components as $T^{a_1,...,a_k}_{b_1,...,b_k} = T(a_1,...,a_k,b_1,...,b_k)$. Where $a_i$ and $\{b_i\}$ are a basis of the vector space and covector space. For definition 2 I see tensor component written as :
>   \begin{align}
> \sum\sum A_{ij}a_i\otimes b_j
> \end{align}
>   How do these components relate ?

Components *do* depend on a choice of basis. The choice of notation used in your textbook was bad, we only keep indices on $T$, not the vectors. I mean one would write $$T^{i_1...i_r}_{\qquad j_1...j_s} \stackrel{\rm def.}{=} T({\bf v}^{i_1},...,{\bf v}^{i_r},{\bf v}_{j_1},...,{\bf v}_{j_s})$$instead. And with this notation, we'd have $$T = \sum_{i_1,...,i_r,j_1,...,j_s} T^{i_1...i_r}_{\qquad j_1...j_s} {\bf v}_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes {\bf v}_{i_r}\otimes {\bf v}^{j_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes {\bf v}^{j_s}.$$With Einstein's summation convention, we'd only write $$T = T^{i_1...i_r}_{\qquad j_1...j_s} {\bf v}_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes {\bf v}_{i_r}\otimes {\bf v}^{j_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes {\bf v}^{j_s}$$
with all the summations implied (and that's why index balance is good - if the same index appears twice, up and below, sum over it).

When you ask how these things relate, the reasonable thing to consider is another basis $\{{{\bf v}_i}'\}$, the corresponding dual basis $\{{{\bf v}^i}'\}$, write $${T^{i_1...i_r}_{\qquad j_1...j_s}}' = T({{\bf v}^{i_1}}',...,{{\bf v}^{i_r}}',{{\bf v}_{j_1}}',...,{{\bf v}_{j_s}}')$$and see how we can express this in terms of the "old" components $T^{i_1...i_r}_{\qquad j_1...j_s}$.

If you're still alive after all that index juggling, you'll certainly pardon me by ilustrating the relation only in the $(1,1)$ case. Write ${{\bf v}_j}' = \sum_i \alpha_{ij} v_i$. It is an easy linear algebra exercise to check that ${{\bf v}^j}' = \sum_i \beta_{ij} {\bf v}^i$, where $(\beta_{ij})$ is the inverse matrix of $(\alpha_{ij})$. Then $${T^i_{\hspace{1ex} j}}'=T({{\bf v}^i}',{{\bf v}_j}') = \sum_{k, \ell }\beta_{ki}\alpha_{\ell j}T({{\bf v}^k}',{{\bf v}^\ell}') = \sum_{k,\ell} \beta_{ki}\alpha_{\ell j}T^k_{\hspace{1ex}\ell}.$$

If we had more entries, then more $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s would pop out. You can see that in any physics book, for instance. I like *A Short Course in General Relativity*, by Foster & Nightingale. By the way, it is costumary to denote the entries of the inverse matrix by writing indices upstairs. In this notation, and using Einstein's convention, we'd have simply $${T^i_{\hspace{1ex} j}}' = \alpha^{ki}\alpha_{\ell j}T^k_{\hspace{1ex} \ell}.$$

> 3) I was trying to work out a basic example of an endomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by using the two definitions but couldn't end up with the same set of components...

When we write components in a basis, they're real numbers, and our discussion does not  quite apply if the codomain of the bilinear map isn't $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need more time to study it. Will comeback with further questions :)

Comment: No worries! ${}{}$

Comment: So basically the tensor product space linearize everything. Making an isomorphism between multi-linear maps and linear maps. Is the proof easy to derive for such a general result ? In my book the author only prove that a $V^* \otimes V$ is isomorphic to the set of maps of the type $ V \times V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and then proceed to generalize to multilinear maps without any proof.

Comment: Yes! Nice way to see it. The proof isn't too different from that initial case you said. Try to mimic it in the $(1,2)$ or $(2,3)$ case instead of the $(1,1)$ case to see the pattern.

Comment: Could you help me understand why the space of multilinear map you mentioned is isomorphic to the tensor product ? Why do we consider a tensor as a multilinear map ? Thank you !

Comment: Take a look at page 366 in Steven Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra. Maybe you'll find the rest of the chapter also useful. We consider a tensor a multilinear map precisely because of that isomorphism.

Comment: I fail to see where in page 366 the answer of my question is. I can only see on 367 the discussion of bilinearity induce linearity on the tensor product. But not why the space of multilinear map is isomorphic to the space of the tensor product. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Got the answer page 386. Thanks !!

Comment: Sorry for not pinpointing more exactly, I just recalled that the interesting part started around there! :P

Answer (score 0):

1. The way to compute the results of applying a tensor to some entries is to apply the first basic element of the tensor to the first entry, the second to the second, and so on, and then perform a summation over what you have left.
   $T(u,v)H(x,y)$=$T_{i,j}(\epsilon ^{i}(u)\epsilon^{j}(v))H_{k,l}(\epsilon^{k}(x)\epsilon^{l}(y)$=$T_{i,j}H_{k,l}\epsilon^{i}(u)\epsilon^{j}(v)\epsilon^{k}(x)\epsilon^{l}(y)$=$(T\otimes H)(u,v,x,y)$
2. The components of a tensor are the tensor being applied to the basis elements.

So a tensor with components $T^{i}_{j,k}$=$T(\epsilon ^{i},e_{j},e_{k})$ can be expressed as follows:

$T^{i}_{j,k}(e_{i}\otimes\epsilon^{j}\otimes\epsilon ^{k})(\epsilon^{a},e_{b},e_{c})$= $T^{i}_{j,k}(e_{i}(\epsilon^{a})\epsilon^{j}(e_{b}) \epsilon^{k}(e_{c}))$=$T^{i}_{j,k}(\delta_{i}^{a}\delta^{j}_{b}\delta^{k}_{c})$

Recalling the krownecker delta index rule, we have it equal to
$T^{a}_{b,c}$ after a summation over the repeated indices.